# sequential drawing / animation iOS

Tags: objective-c, drawing, animated

i have an array of uibezierpath's.
how could I draw each path in sequence, but with a delay so it appears animated?
I am currently drawing the whole array like this (and technically, it is sequential i think, but so fast it appears all at once):

```
for (UIBezierPath * path in myArrayOfBezierPaths){
    path.lineWidth=3;
    [path stroke];
    [path release];
}
```

lastly, how could I make each path a different color?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to redraw the view multiple times, each time drawing more of your paths. To accomplish this, you need use a timer of some kind and have a way to keep track of which paths you're drawing.

To keep track of the paths you could use an `NSInteger` instance variable and increment it each time another path is drawn, then in `-drawRect:` check the value of that variable and draw the appropriate number of paths.

Then you would implement a method that updates the ivar and redraws the view. Here is a very simplistic version:

```
//assume pathsToDraw is an NSInteger ivar
//and that myArrayOfBezierPaths is an NSArray ivar
//containing UIBezierPath objects


- (void)startDrawingPaths
{
    //draw the first path
    pathsToDraw = 1;
    [view setNeedsDisplay];

    //schedule redraws once per second
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(updateView:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

- (void)updateView:(NSTimer*)timer
{
    //increment the path counter
    pathsDrawn++;

    //tell the view to update
    [view setNeedsDisplay];

    //if we've drawn all our paths, stop the timer
    if(pathsDrawn >= [myArrayOfBezierPaths count])
    {
        [timer invalidate];
    }
}
```

Your drawing method would look something like this:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    NSInteger i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < pathsDrawn; i++) 
    {
        UIBezierPath * path = [myArrayOfBezierPaths objectAtIndex:i];
        path.lineWidth=3;
        [path stroke];
    }
}
```

As far as color goes, you're creating the paths, so you can make them whatever color you like.